# com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line

Tags: android-volley

"com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line"

I tried to get response array by using Volley library some url , many of its working good but some of these not working at any time.

all are done by same process

I'm new to android

whenever I tried these url I'm getting above error

in browser it working fine ..

please give me any solution...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Hi did you get the solution for this issue

Comment: same problem here...